# how can I use @Enclosed without making methods as static

Tags: java, junit, static, inner-classes

I need to have different sets of parameters so I decided to use [@Enclosed](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/src-html/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html#line.26). However, the nested classes have to be static and therefore all existing methods/constants called by the methods have to be static.
But it is hard because I cannot change the definition of all these methods.

Is there any way to use @Enclosed without adding the definition of existing methods with static?

Here is an example so that you know what I am asking. In the example, since data() is static, class someTest has to be static, so if I call nonStaticMethod(), I got "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method..." at the line calling nonStaticMethod().
But I do not want to redefine nonStaticMethod() to static.

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class EnclosedParameterizedTest extends EnclosedBase{

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class SomeTest {

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                    new Object[]{"NY"},
                    new Object[]{"CA"},
            });
        }

        String state;

        public SomeTest(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Test
        public void verifyStateTest(){
            nonStaticMethod(); //a method already defined in parent of     
            //EnclosedBase which I cannot re-define
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Enclosed` runner requires that the enclosed classes be static (aka "nested classes").

**Edit:** in fact, JUnit will never instantiate the class annotated with `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)`. Having a test that uses `Enclosed` extend another class doesn't do anything unless the base class has fields or methods annotated with JUnit annotations (`@ClassRule`, `@BeforeClass`, etc).

I suggest that you **share code via delegation, not inheritance**. In your case, you can move `nonStaticMethod()` to a different class:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class EnclosedParameterizedTest {

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class SomeTest {
        public final Helper helper = new Helper();

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                    new Object[] { "NY" },
                    new Object[] { "CA" },
            });
        }

        String state;

        public SomeTest(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Test
        public void verifyStateTest(){
            helper.nonStaticMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

In general, delegation is more flexible than inheritance. One common problem with inheritance in Java is that a class can have only one base class. But another problem is that nested classes can't access the outer class's state, so cannot share code other than static methods.

**Edit:** If that isn't an option, your nested classes can extend your base class:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class EnclosedParameterizedTest {

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class SomeTest extends EnclosedBase {

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                    new Object[] { "NY" },
                    new Object[] { "CA" },
            });
        }

        String state;

        public SomeTest(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Test
        public void verifyStateTest(){
            nonStaticMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want different sets of parameters for different tests, **consider using the [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams) runner**:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class MyParameterizedTest extends EnclosedBase {

    @Parameters({"NY", 
                 "CA" })
    @Test
    public void verifyStateTest(String state) {
        nonStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks NamshubWriter. I have to inherit from base class. it is out of my control. I am still trying to understand how good JUnitParams is.

Comment: @user389955 I edited my answer to clarify the limitations of the `Enclosed` runner, and to provide another suggested solution

Answer (score 4):

This is something a lot of people get confused about. All that is meant by "static nested class" is that the inner class doesn't have a reference to the outer class. There's no requirement that the methods or fields be made static.

As an example, lookup the source for java.util.HashMap, there's a static inner class called Entry that implements `java.util.Map.Entry`:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    int hash;

    /**
     * Creates new entry.
     */
    Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry<K,V> n) {
        value = v;
        next = n;
        key = k;
        hash = h;
    }

    public final K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public final V getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    // ...
```

Obviously a map has to have multiple entries, so the `static` keyword is not being used to indicate this is some kind of singleton.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I am not sure if we are discussing the same thing. I have edited the original post and hope you know how to call nonStaticMethod() without redefine it as static.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. Without Enclosed.class, I can directly call nonStaticMethod() in EnclosedParameterizedTest because it is a method inherited from EnclosedParameterizedTest's grandpa class. it is weird that now I have to call EnclosedParameterizedTest.this.nonStaticMethod(). By the way EnclosedParameterizedTest.this.nonStaticMethod() does not work.

Comment: @user389955: right, EnclosedParameterizedTest.this.nonStaticMethod doesn't work because being in a static inner class means there's no reference to the outer `this`.